# How to resolve "Rscript not found" error when executing r.futures.potential in GRASS GIS?

Tags: python, r, grass-gis

I'm trying to run a Python simulation script in GRASS GIS 8.3.1 on Windows that utilizes the r.futures module. I get the following error when the r.futures.potential command is reached:

> ERROR: Rscript required for running r.futures.potential, but not
> found. Make sure you have R installed and added to the PATH.

I have R 4.3.0 installed, and these four R packages and their dependencies: **MumIn, lme4, optparse, rgrass**. I've also added the following path to System Variables

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.0"
```

restarted GRASS GIS, restarted the system but I get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it can't find it, but you can execute from the GRASS terminal:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.0\bin
```

This should make Rscript available, but it's adding it to the PATH only for that terminal session.

Comment: I've tried that, it did not work. The program gives the same error message when running the r.futures.potential command. The program works fine for GRASS GIS 8.2 though.